# A reoccurring value?

Tags: function

I'm a beginner in python and having trouble with finding the 2nd reoccurring values in the list. Note, trying to make this simple as possible without enumerate or count func and just loops and lists.

My code so far:

```
def find_second_occurrence(xs,v):
    num_occurrence = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        for j in range(v):
            if (xs)[i] == (v)[j]:
                num_occurrence = i
            return str((xs,v)[num_occurrence])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has some issues, first your inner loop:

```
    for j in range(v):
        if (xs)[i] == (v)[j]:
            num_occurrence = i
```

Is firstly not really required and secondly an error. `v` is an `int` and *cannot* be subscripted with `(v)[j]`, an appropriate Exception will be raised for that. (and by the way, parentheses around a name don't do much `xs[i]` is the same as `(xs)[i]` only way more visually appealing)

Then, your return statement:

```
str((xs,v)[num_occurrence])
```

Is creating a tuple `(xs, v)` and then indexing with `[num_occurence]` which will again be an exception: `IndexError` signaling that you exceeded the bounds for the tuple index.

Without using `enumerate` or any such built-ins, you can simply use a flag to indicate if the number has been found once, and act on that when iterating through the rest, i.e:

```
def find_second_occurrence(xs, v):
    found = False
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] == v and found:
            return i
        if xs[i] == v:
            found = True
    return "Not found"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I see what I did wrong and the Index error was good to note.